# how to get max time from max date in the same table in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
select sync_date, max(sync_end_time),user_code from sync_tracker where 
sync_action = 'COMPLETION' 
and sync_status = 'SUCCESS'
and user_code in (select ut.code from user_table ut
   join user_location_mapping ulm
   on ut.code = ulm.user_code) 
and sync_date = MAX(sync_date)-- can't even write aggregate function
group by sync_date,user_code
order by sync_date desc

User_code recent_login_date recent_login_time
0012      2016_11_11        11:30:23
0013      2016_1_19         12:30:23
0014      2016_12_4         1:30:23
```

I want recent date and time where those are different column. 
Please help me find out the same, it is giving error that I should use 'EXISTS' as the sbquery return multiple number of records.

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of using `MAX(sync_date)` you can try a subquery `SELECT MAX(sync_date) FROM user_table WHERE <conditions>`

Comment: thanks for quick reply, and for time? not working

Comment: Can you show please the structure of your table, some data and your expected result?

Comment: Please show sample table data along with your expected output.

Comment: expected output is   `User_code  recent_login_date  recent_login_time`

Comment: Provide tables with some data in it and expected output or else we can't help you much

Answer (score 0):

```
    select st.user_code, tAux.dateMax, max(st.sync_end_time) as timeMax
    from sync_tracker st
    inner join 
    (
    select user_code, max(sync_date) as dateMax
    from sync_tracker 
    inner join user_table ut on user_code = ut.code
    inner join user_location_mapping ulm on ut.code = ulm.user_code
    where sync_action = 'COMPLETION' 
    and sync_status = 'SUCCESS'
    group by user_code, sync_date
    ) tAux
    on st.user_code = tAux.user_code and st.sync_date = tAux.dateMax
    group by st.user_code, tAux.dateMax
    order by dateMax, timeMax
```

Comment: Thank you for your post@Fran Cerezo, sometimes you cant find answer, as scenario can not be explained clearly, I attached modified_date in the table, which is helping me draw the answer.